# Google Earth Plugin changing time slider with 1 day interval as a "tick" for pressing next button (like the Historical Images time slider)

Tags: kml, google-earth, timespan, google-earth-plugin

I want to create a time slider with 1 day interval as a "tick" for pressing next button.

Currently, I set each TimeSpans:

```
  <TimeSpan>
    <begin>2013-04-23T12:00:00Z</begin>
    <end>2013-04-24T12:00:00Z</end>
  </TimeSpan>
  <TimeSpan>
    <begin>2013-04-24T12:00:00Z</begin>
    <end>2013-04-25T12:00:00Z</end>
  </TimeSpan>
```

But the time interval for pressing next button is 4 hours instead of 1 day.
Is there a way to change the time interval from 4 hours to 1 day?

My questions is kind of related to the previous post:
http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/earth/spqsOuVdg7A/6gAfbvKcICIJ